# General approach to handle Task cancellation correctly

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, cancellation

I'm doing a code review, and I'm concerned about this pattern, seen all across that code:

```
try
{
    await DoSomethingAsync();
    await DoSomethingElseAsync();
    // and so on...
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // all good, user cancelled
    // log and return
    return;
}
// handle other particular exceptions
// ...
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // fatal error, alert the user
    FatalErrorMessage(ex);
}
```

The part I'm concerned about is handling `OperationCanceledException`. Shouldn't this code be also handling `AggregateException` and checking if the only *inner* exception is `OperationCanceledException`?

I know `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result` would throw an `AggregateException` like that, rather than `OperationCanceledException`. The author of the code assured me she only uses `async/await` inside out and never uses `Wait/Result`. Thus, she doesn't like the idea of additionally observing `AggregateException` for cancellation. However, my point is some standard `Task`-based BCL APIs could still be wrapping `OperationCanceledException` with `AggregateException`, e.g. because they still might be accessing `Task.Result` internally.

Does it make sense? Should we be worrying about handling both `OperationCanceledException` and `AggregateException` to observe cancellation correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's definitely technically possible which is very easy to verify with this code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Test().Wait();
}

static async Task Test()
{
    try
    {
        await ThrowAggregate();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

static async Task ThrowAggregate()
{
    ThrowException().Wait();
}

static async Task ThrowException()
{
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
}
```

`ThrowAggregate` stores the AggregateException inside the returned task so awaiting it still throws `AggregateException`. So if you want to be diligent you would need to catch `AggregateException` too.

However, it's **very unlikely** that any method in the BCL would do that and if it did you have bigger issues than exception handling since your doing async over sync. 
I would be more worried about your own code.

Comment: Thank you @arnon, this sounds reasonable, I'll accept it as an answer in a little while.

Answer (score 6):

> However, my point is some standard Task-based BCL APIs could still be wrapping OperationCanceledException with AggregateException, e.g. because they still might be accessing Task.Result internally.

No, they won't do that.

> Should we be worrying about handling both OperationCanceledException and AggregateException to observe cancellation correctly?

I would say no. It is, of course, *possible* that an `AggregateException` can contain an `OperationCanceledException`, but it can also contain `other particular exceptions` just as easily.

As long as you follow async best practices (i.e., no async-over-sync or sync-over-async), then you don't have to worry about this.